# Query with filter builder on nested array using MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Consider the following object structure stored as documents:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FooBar> Bars { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class FooBar
{
    public string BarId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Using a LINQ-style query with the driver I can `Find` all `Foo` that contain a `FooBar` `BarId` like this:

```
var foos = await m_fooCollection.Find( f => f.Bars.Any( fb => fb.BarId == "123") ).ToListAsync();
```

How can I achieve this same query using the [`FilterDefinitionBuilder`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/#filter-definition-builder) instead of the in-line LINQ on `Find`?

Comment: It isn't LINQ, just a lambda expression.

Comment: `.Any` on a `ICollection` is part of the `Enumerable` class in the `System.Linq` namespace, right?

Comment: Indeed, but that method will never be called. The driver translates the expression to a mongo query.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I guess I was more trying to express the fact that I am using LINQ style syntax rather than actual LINQ.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really matter. Just a note to future googlers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The query you need to perform uses the `$elemMatch` query operator.

So, this query using a lambda expression

```
var findFluent = collection.Find(f => f.Bars.Any(fb => fb.BarId == "123"));
```

Is equivalent to this query using the `FilterDefinitionBuilder`:

```
var findFluent = collection.Find(Builders<Foo>.Filter.ElemMatch(
    foo => foo.Bars, 
    foobar => foobar.BarId == "123"));
```

Comment: What if I have BarNumber property instead of BarId and there are 2 BarNumber with same value. How can I get both of them?

Comment: @i3arnon, this returns all the `Foo` objects that matches the criteria with each object having ALL its `FooBar` children. What if I need to filter those children objects too (with `BarId = "123"`) so not all FooBar will be present in result?

Comment: @benjamin54 I don't think you can do that with a "simple" query. I think you need to use the aggregation framework, but I'm not sure. Maybe you'd be better posing another question...

Comment: Hey, if `Foo` object has a dateTime property, which I want to find by date greaterorequal param, how would you achieve that?
Doing like so doesnt work ->
var findFluent = collection.Find(Builders<Foo>.Filter.ElemMatch(
    foo => foo.Bars, 
    foobar => foobar.TimeCreate >= timeParam));

Comment: what if I need to compare any entire child object like this? Like imagine changing the last part of your query to ... foobar => foobar.child == someobject)) Is this possible?

Comment: @benjamin54 i am looking for the same answer that you asked.
I am late here but looking forward to hear form you! Please let me know if we can do that using FilterDefinitionBuilder ? otherwise projection is the option to do it.